# LocationManager dispatch queue Issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

What I have built:

I have built a simple `GMSMapView` with `CLLocationManagerDelegate` that just tracks users's current location and update on `GMSMapView`.

Issue:

When the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` (the `GMSMapView` screen) opens directly it works just fine, but when I try to reach to the `GMSMapView` screen using a `segue` it pushes an error.

A location manager (`0x145e5f9e0`) was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread.  It is the developer's responsibility to ensure that there is a run loop running on the thread on which the location manager object is allocated.  In particular, creating location managers in arbitrary dispatch queues (not attached to the main queue) is not supported and will result in callbacks not being received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Swift 3**. So the Issue was with the Initialization of the variables `GMSMapView` and `CLLocationManager`. This Is how It worked for me:

I defined variables in the `ViewController` class as below

```
private var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
private var googleMapView: GMSMapView!
```

And in the `viewDidLoad()` I introduced a `DispatchQueue` to run it in main thread.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //adding mapView
        self.googleMapView = GMSMapView()
        self.view.addSubview(self.googleMapView)
        self.googleMapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //auto layout constraints
        self.googleMapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.googleMapView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.googleMapView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.googleMapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        //location manager  setup
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async
{
  /*your code here*/
};
```

Comment: I have literally removed all of the code from ViewController only `GMSMapView` Instance is there and still the same error and got no code left to add in `DispatchQueue`.

Comment: Same error! Seems like something's wrong with `GMSMapView` Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code for finding location into dispatch queue instead of main queue.

Comment: @John Welliem....please refer this link
https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/blocks-ios-introduction-to-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: An answer that's bit more specific would be much appreciated.